# select specific area in an xml

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a small application in PHP that should get some data from XML in order to calculate some bills.

I have this XML to use:
http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2016.xml

It already returns me an array, the parse is not a problem.
I do not know though how to display only the data from a specific date.
Let's say I want to use the currencies from 1/5/2016. How do I do that?

There is also an XML available for each day. If I use that, the code looks like this: `var_dump($array['Body']['Cube']['Rate'][10])` for example. I don't know how to select the body with a specific attribute. In this case, the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath selector, it allows quite sophisticated queries:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.bnr.ro/xsd');
$result = $xml->xpath('/a:DataSet/a:Body/a:Cube[@date="2016-01-05"]/a:Rate');
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You register the namespace prefix without using it, like: `/a:DataSet/a:Body/a:Cube[@date="2016-01-05"]/a:Rate`.

Comment: @ThW you are right, i fixed the query. [Demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5b3c31bfd91c252c9a6a55cac964e8a3d452c20)